# CSS interpreter for custom GUI renderer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, rendering

I'm working on a renderer which layouts visual GUI objects according to CSS rules.
The renderer takes two inputs: object tree and css rules.
Each object has position, size, color, etc.
Output is set of properties which if applied to the objects will result in layout corresponding to the input CSS rules.

An ideal example usage:

```
var renderer = new GUI_Renderer_CSS();
renderer.setRootContainterSize(840,200);
renderer.setParentToChildRelativePositions(true);

var css = "
   .menu {
        padding: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
    }
    .item {
        height: 30px;
        margin: 20px;
        background-color: red;
    }
    #special {
        margin: 40px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
";

var objects = [{
    class:"menu"; 
    id="1"; 
    width:"300px";  // here the width is carried by the object itself
    children: [ 
        {class:"item"; id="2";}, 
        {class:"item"; id="3";}, 
        {class:"item"; id:"special"; } 
    ];
}];


var renderedProperties = renderer.render(objects, css);

// renderedProperties dump:
{
          1: { x:100px; y:100px; width:300px; height:210px; background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255)},
          2: { x:20px;  y:20px;  width:260px; height:30px;  background-color:rgb(255, 0, 0)},
          3: { x:20px;  y:50px;  width:260px; height:30px;  background-color:rgb(255, 0, 0)},
    special: { x:40px;  y:80px;  width:220px; height:30px;  background-color:rgb(255, 255, 0)},
}

renderer.getRootContainterSize(); // 840 x 410  // height is recalculated based on real space required by the rendered objects
```

Note that the purpose of this is not to be used in a browser nor with HTML.

Question: does something like this already exist? If not, is there anything I can start with?

Comment: just curious, where exactly you're planning to use this if not in browser/html? Is it going to be in a phone app which wraps your html/css?

Comment: just a generic GUI renderer. I have thick (non-html, non-browser) apps written in JS. I need to layout the GUI elements somehow and CSS seemed to be nice candidate. I need margins/paddings/variable sizes simply all the good things already once developed for HTML/CSS.